# How to filter by month in AngularJs with filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to filter data using AngularJs filter in a ng-repeat.

Here is my ng-repeat snippet

```
<tr ng-repeat="finance in finances | filter:trierParDate ">
    <td>{{finance.created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{finance.prix | numeraljs:'argent'}}</td>
    <td>{{finance.grandtotal | numeraljs:'argent'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Here is my buttons to filter by months:

```
<div ng-click="trierParDate = {'created_at': '2015-03-12 22:43:07'}">Janvier</div>
<div ng-click="trierParDate = {'created_at': '2015-03-12 22:43:07'}">Février</div>
etc...
```

Actually, these "buttons" returns a single entry as I just wanted to test it. Now I wonder how to filter by month.

I would like that translates to: ng-click = {if the created_at property contains 03 at position 5 to 7 (month data position), then show the entries.}

Answer (score 1):

You can create a filter function, and filter results based on a selected / desired month.  Here's a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/OTTAqykqGsJFrFyJYOjD?p=preview

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    Show results for 
    <select ng-model = "selectedMonth">
      <option></option>
      <option value="0">Jan</option>  
      <option value="1">Feb</option>  
      <option value="2">Mar</option>  
      <option value="3">Apr</option>  
      <option value="4">May</option>  
      <option value="5">Jun</option>  
      <option value="6">Jul</option>  
      <option value="7">Aug</option>  
      <option value="8">Sep</option>  
      <option value="9">Oct</option>  
      <option value="10">Nov</option>  
      <option value="11">Dec</option>  
    </select>

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="a in appointments | filter: selectedMonthFilter">id: {{a.id}}, label: {{a.label}}, created: {{a.created}}</li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.appointments = [];

  $scope.selectedMonth = "";

  $scope.selectedMonthFilter = function(element) {
    if(!$scope.selectedMonth) return true;
    return element.created.getMonth() == $scope.selectedMonth;
  }

  function randomDate(start, end) {
      return new Date(start.getTime() + Math.random() * (end.getTime() - start.getTime()))
  }  

  for(var i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    $scope.appointments.push({id: i, label: "Item number " + i, created: randomDate(new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date())});
  }

});
```

Comment: This snippet works. I try to figure out how to adapt it to my code. I'm working on it right now.

Comment: Note that the filtered date must be a Date object for this to work - so if you're filtering data from an API, convert it to a Date object.