# how to filter dates with angular?

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php. I have a "select" option where I choose specific date and it shows me all details in a table, and counting on several things and everything works great. but when I pick a date, i want it to show all results by specific month and not by specific date(for example --> now i choose date like this - '2016-4-15' it will give me all information specific to this date and not by month like i need). can someone please help? in my database the 'date' value is date.

Php query :

```
$query=" SELECT `description` ,`total_price` , `name`,`supplier_id`,`date` FROM `suppliers`,`expenses`
  where `supplier_id` = `refer_supplier_id`   ";
```

Html:

```
   <select ng-model="supplierExpenses.selectedOption" ng-change="setTotals(supplierExpenses)"
        ng-options = "item.date for item in supplierExpenses |
        unique:'date'" >

        <option value="">בחר תאריך</option>
        </select>



 <div class="table-responsive">
 <table class="customer-list table table-striped" >
            <thead>
                 <tr >

                     <th class="Column-Header">מספר ספק</th>
                     <th class="Column-Header">שם ספק</th>
                     <th class="Column-Header">כמות מוצרים שנקנו</th>
                     <th class="Column-Header">מחיר הוצאה</th>

                 </tr>
             </thead>
             <tbody>
                 <tr ng-repeat="item in supplierExpenses" ng-if = "item.date == supplierExpenses.selectedOption.date"
                  >

                     <td>{{item.supplier_id}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                     <td>{{item.total_price}}</td>

                 </tr>
             </tbody>
             <tfoot>

                 <tr class="bg-warning">
                     <td><font size="6">סה"כ הוצאות</font></td>
                     <td><font size="6">{{totalExpenses}}</font></td>
                     <td></td>
                 </tr>
             </tfoot>

         </table>


 </div>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";
angular.module('dataSystem').controller('supplierExpensesCtrl', function ($scope, $route, $location, $http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/reports-tab/supplier-expenses-by-mounth.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.supplierExpenses = arr;
      })

      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      });

      $scope.totalExpenses = 0;
      $scope.setTotals = function(totalItem){
        $scope.totalExpenses = 0;
        for(var item =0; item< totalItem.length; item++){
          //  console.log(totalItem[item]);
          if (totalItem[item] && (totalItem[item].date == $scope.supplierExpenses.selectedOption.date)){

            $scope.totalExpenses += parseInt(totalItem[item].total_price);
           }
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: do you want a `GROUP BY month`  or `WHERE row.date = @month`? show us sample data  current and expected result. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza thanks for the tips. I want to select a month and to get all data from that specific month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter by month in AngularJs with filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241696/how-to-filter-by-month-in-angularjs-with-filter)

Comment: thanks for the help @JuanCarlosOropeza

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi glad you succeed with the total ^^ I edit my answer with the working solution for the date issue

```
$http({method:'GET', url:'api/reports-tab/supplier-expenses-by-mounth.php/'})
      .then(function(response) { 
          var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data)), month, date; 
          for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++){ 
              date = new Date(arr[i].date); //we convert the string into javascript date
              month = date.getMonth()+1; 
              if(month.length === 1){ 
                  month = '0'+month; //we add a 0 if needed
              } 
              var year = date.getFullYear(); 
              arr[i].date = month+'/'+year; //we use only the month and year
          } 
          $scope.supplierExpenses = arr; 

      })
```

Comment: it doesn't work:( the table is being shown without me picking a date.

Comment: could you add the formatedDate() function to see what could be wrong ?

Comment: I added - there are no errors. the table I being shown before I pick some date

Comment: can we continue with chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121264/discussion-between-tanyaa-and-dmcissokho).